# Amazon Rekognition Image caption

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

In Azure Cognitive Image processing the returned json have a "caption" field which summarizes the content of the image. However, I didn't find anything similar in AWS.

In Amazon Rekognition for image processing how do I get the caption for an image?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [DetectLabels - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectLabels.html) command:

> Detects instances of real-world entities within an image (JPEG or PNG) provided as input. This includes objects like flower, tree, and table; events like wedding, graduation, and birthday party; and concepts like landscape, evening, and nature.

Comment: DetectLabels returns a list of labels and there confidence score. What I am looking is a caption.     [Image Processing with the Computer Vision API | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) If you check the returned json under `description` there is a tag `caption` which explains the scene in the picture. I am looking for something similar.